# Coloring Images through a Palette Android

Tags: android, color-picker

I was wondering is there a way to color the images dynamically through a palette?

The coloring being similar to the bucket in paint i.e. [coloring areas bounded by outlines]

I want to color different images e.g. a kid, a tree etc. the user should be able to color the face of the kid by any color on the palette [making it similar to the bucket in MS Paint], but I am lost on how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there a particular problem you're having? We generally only answer specific answers here on stack overflow.

Comment: i just want to create a color dropper, is it possible? is there any help available..

Comment: That's no more specific. You're asking too broad of a question. You need to narrow down what you want to ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the [Flood Fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)  :)

Comment: This is what i am looking for. But its implementation would be a tricky one. Ill try it, thanks for atleast routing me to a nice algo .